# How to embed images in e-mails sent by msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to send e-mails to contacts stored in SQL Server database. The e-mails contain images.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp&#95;send&#95;dbmail<br/>
   @recipients = 'name@address.com;',<br/>
   @subject = 'Sending Mail from SQL Server Test',<br/>
   @file_attachments = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pagerror.gif',<br/>
   @body=N'&lt;img src="pagerror.gif" /&gt;',<br/> 
   @body_format = 'HTML';
```

but some e-mail providers (like Yahoo) assume the sent mail as spam. What i need is to create the <img> tag like the ones generated by Outlook:

<img width=482 height=675 id="_x0000_i1025" src="cid:image002.png@01CA4B5E.28AE48C0">

With this tag, Yahoo doesn't assume it as spam. How to process the image so I can refer it like above?

I'm not an advanced SQL Server programmer. I really need a step-by-step tutorial. Please help...

Comment: For additional info, by using the first command, the image is not embedded in Yahoo, but attached. I don't see any image in the e-mail content.

Comment: Host the image online somewhere and use the online address for the src="http://yourdomain.com/pagerror.gif" and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If the image resides on another server and you are just referring to it in your mail, then follow Jonathans comment.

If sending image as attachment is fine, you could use something like this...

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @recipients = 'name@address.com;',
    @subject = 'Sending Mail from SQL Server Test',
    @body_format = 'HTML',
    @query = 'SELECT imageField FROM Person WHERE ID = 12345',
    @execute_query_database = 'YourDatabase',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'imageOfAPerson.jpg'
```

If nothing of the kind is good for you, you can use CLR functionality of SQL server and develop your own piece of code to send an arbitrary email. I believe you don't have a clue how to do it and it can be rather complex, but that's how it is. There is no easy way around it.